# system_monitor package in autoware.universe is giving the following error while launching

Tags: ros2

When I try to launch system_monitor package in autoware.universe by
ros2 launch system_monitor system_monitor.launch.xml
I get the following error.
[ERROR 1696999498.890117924] [net_monitor]: Failed to connect socket. No such file or directory (connect_service() at /home/shivani/autoware/src/universe/autoware.universe/system/system_monitor/src/net_monitor/net_monitor.cpp:661)

[image]

Even though the node is publishing data just fine. I want to know the reason for this error and how to fix this. Thanks!